# trigonometric equations calculations and their implementation in practise.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin (11x)\sin (x) = \cos (10x) $$

How can one solve this ? The formulas for summation or doubling dont seem to be of much help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\displaystyle2\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B),$

$\displaystyle\implies 2\sin11x\sin x=\cos(10x)-\cos12x$

We have $\displaystyle2\sin11x\sin x=2\cos10x$

$\displaystyle\implies 2\cos10x=\cos(10x)-\cos12x$

$\displaystyle\implies\cos10x=-\cos12x=\cos(\pi-12x)$ as $\cos(\pi-y)=-\cos y$

$\displaystyle\implies  10x=2n\pi\pm(\pi-12x)$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: comparing two cosines?

Comment: how did you get to the last stage?

Comment: @Bak1139, we know $\cos A=\cos B\implies A=2n\pi\pm B$

Comment: @Bak1139, See also, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: man, you're a necromancer!:) thanks...

Comment: @Bak1139, not sure how I've come across this , but immediately I felt to add those links. Anyway, my pleasure

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\sin(10x+x) = \sin(10x)\cos(x) + \cos(10x)\sin(x)$$

Comment: could please elaborate the next steps?